# trying to use vector<vector<int>> in a class

Tags: c++

starting to learn classes in c++ and i came across a simple board game... but i got this insane amount of error that i cant solve.

if i shouldn't post this kind of question here, please advise me.

Board.h:

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class Board{
    int largura;
    int altura;
public:
    Board(int x,int y) : largura(x), altura(y) {}
    vector<vector<int> > mat();
    void printa();
};
```

Board.cpp:

```
#include "Board.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int> > Board::mat() {
    vector<vector<int> > v(altura, vector<int>(largura,1));
    return v;
}

void Board::printa() {
    auto matriz = mat();
    vector<int> vec(largura,0);
    for(;;) {
        for (auto i:vec) {
            for (auto j:vec) {
                cout << matriz[i,j];
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Board.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Board tela(5, 5);
    tela.mat();
    tela.printa();
    return 0;
}
```

the error:

```
[Rafael@localhost untitled]$ g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp Board.cpp -o board
Board.cpp: In member function ‘void Board::printa()’:
Board.cpp:22:22: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’)
                 cout << matriz[i,j];

In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39:0,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:108:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:108:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type&) {aka std::basic_ostream<char>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&)}’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:117:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]
       operator<<(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:117:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type&) {aka std::basic_ios<char>& (*)(std::basic_ios<char>&)}’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:127:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
       operator<<(ios_base& (*__pf) (ios_base&))
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:127:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:166:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
       operator<<(long __n)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:166:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘long int’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:170:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
       operator<<(unsigned long __n)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:170:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘long unsigned int’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:174:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
       operator<<(bool __n)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:174:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘bool’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:638:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/ostream.tcc:91:5: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/ostream.tcc:91:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘short int’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39:0,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:181:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
       operator<<(unsigned short __n)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:181:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘short unsigned int’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:638:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/ostream.tcc:105:5: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/ostream.tcc:105:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘int’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39:0,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:192:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
       operator<<(unsigned int __n)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:192:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘unsigned int’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:201:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
       operator<<(long long __n)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:201:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘long long int’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:205:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
       operator<<(unsigned long long __n)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:205:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘long long unsigned int’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:220:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
       operator<<(double __f)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:220:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘double’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:224:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
       operator<<(float __f)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:224:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘float’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:232:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
       operator<<(long double __f)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:232:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘long double’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:245:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
       operator<<(const void* __p)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:245:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘const void*’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:638:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/ostream.tcc:119:5: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]
     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/ostream.tcc:119:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__streambuf_type* {aka std::basic_streambuf<char>*}’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/basic_string.h:5325:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/basic_string.h:5325:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Board.cpp:22:35: note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’ is not derived from ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
                 cout << matriz[i,j];
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/ios_base.h:46:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/system_error:209:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::error_code&)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, const error_code& __e)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/system_error:209:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Board.cpp:22:35: note:   cannot convert ‘matriz.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >(((void)0, ((std::vector<std::vector<int> >::size_type)j)))’ (type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’) to type ‘const std::error_code&’
                 cout << matriz[i,j];
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39:0,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:497:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, _CharT __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:497:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Board.cpp:22:35: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_CharT’ (‘char’ and ‘std::vector<int>’)
                 cout << matriz[i,j];
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39:0,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:502:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, char)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, char __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:502:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Board.cpp:22:35: note:   cannot convert ‘matriz.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >(((void)0, ((std::vector<std::vector<int> >::size_type)j)))’ (type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’) to type ‘char’
                 cout << matriz[i,j];
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39:0,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:508:5: note: candidate: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, char)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, char __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:508:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Board.cpp:22:35: note:   cannot convert ‘matriz.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >(((void)0, ((std::vector<std::vector<int> >::size_type)j)))’ (type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’) to type ‘char’
                 cout << matriz[i,j];
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39:0,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:514:5: note: candidate: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, signed char)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, signed char __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:514:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Board.cpp:22:35: note:   cannot convert ‘matriz.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >(((void)0, ((std::vector<std::vector<int> >::size_type)j)))’ (type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’) to type ‘signed char’
                 cout << matriz[i,j];
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39:0,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:519:5: note: candidate: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, unsigned char __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:519:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Board.cpp:22:35: note:   cannot convert ‘matriz.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >(((void)0, ((std::vector<std::vector<int> >::size_type)j)))’ (type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’) to type ‘unsigned char’
                 cout << matriz[i,j];
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39:0,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:539:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const _CharT*)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, const _CharT* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:539:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Board.cpp:22:35: note:   mismatched types ‘const _CharT*’ and ‘std::vector<int>’
                 cout << matriz[i,j];
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:638:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/ostream.tcc:321:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const char*)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/ostream.tcc:321:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Board.cpp:22:35: note:   cannot convert ‘matriz.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >(((void)0, ((std::vector<std::vector<int> >::size_type)j)))’ (type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’) to type ‘const char*’
                 cout << matriz[i,j];
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39:0,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:556:5: note: candidate: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const char*)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:556:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Board.cpp:22:35: note:   cannot convert ‘matriz.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >(((void)0, ((std::vector<std::vector<int> >::size_type)j)))’ (type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’) to type ‘const char*’
                 cout << matriz[i,j];
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39:0,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:569:5: note: candidate: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const signed char*)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const signed char* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:569:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Board.cpp:22:35: note:   cannot convert ‘matriz.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >(((void)0, ((std::vector<std::vector<int> >::size_type)j)))’ (type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’) to type ‘const signed char*’
                 cout << matriz[i,j];
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39:0,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:574:5: note: candidate: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const unsigned char*)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const unsigned char* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:574:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Board.cpp:22:35: note:   cannot convert ‘matriz.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >(((void)0, ((std::vector<std::vector<int> >::size_type)j)))’ (type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}’) to type ‘const unsigned char*’
                 cout << matriz[i,j];
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/iostream:39:0,
                 from Board.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:628:5: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = std::vector<int>] <near match>
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ostream:628:5: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
Board.cpp:22:35: error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
                 cout << matriz[i,j];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[i,j]` is a trap. It's the same thing as `[j]`. What you want is `matriz[i][j];`, not `matriz[i,j]`.

(You should also avoid `using` directives in header files, but that's purely cosmetic. Your problem is the `[i,j]` part.)

Comment: also, another issue is that mat() is creating a temporary board then returning a copy of that. There's no actual permanent board data in the class, each call to mat() will create a new separate board that's not actually stored in the board class.